# How to redirect back to my previous page with submitted request

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-5.3

I want redirect through coding without using session in laravel.
I think this not possible or difficult.

If any solution is their please share with me.

Comment: check if `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is what you're asking about. Be warned though - it can't always be trusted.

Comment: Why can't you use `Redirect::back()->withInput()`?

Answer (score 2):

Hello if you use Laravel 5.1 you can use

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses

```
return back();
```

for Laravel 5.0
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: And I guess it was `return Redirect::back();` in Laravel 4.

Comment: If i have submitted form to another page then i am going to another page then it is possible to get submitted page using return redirect()->back(). I will try but i think it is possible.

Comment: See i am redirecting once again after submitting form that was i saying.

Comment: can you give example what do you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you using PHP, keep a running variable of the current URL with `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and add this as a `GET` parameter.

You will now have a parameter with the information you need to redirect using `header()` or to create your own link.